# Getting total amount of prime numbers

Tags: java, numbers

I have a simple code with a simple objective. I'm still learning Java and what my code does is to count the total amount of prime numbers of a certain number (example: from 11 - 19 there are 4 prime numbers 11,13,17,19). So far What I've able to do is display the prime numbers (11,13,17,19) but I also want to display "4" as the amount of prime numbers on the range of 11-19. this is my code.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {

 //get input till which prime number to be printed
  System.out.println("Enter the number till which prime number to be printed: ");
  int limit = 19;


  System.out.println("Printing prime number from 11 to " + limit);

  for(int number = 11; number<=limit; number++){

      if(isPrime(number))


      {
          System.out.println(number );
      }
  }
}

public static boolean isPrime(int number){
    for(int i=2; i<number; i++){
       if(number%i == 0){
           return false; 
       }
    }
    return true; 
}
```

}

Comment: Then you need to add some code which increments a counter every time you find a prime number.

Comment: you might be interested in this:
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/14array/PrimeSieve.java.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int count = 0;
for(int number = 11; number<=limit; number++){
  if(isPrime(number))
  {
      System.out.println(number);
      count++;
  }
}
System.out.println("Number of primes are :"+count);
```

Comment: uugh.. I actually did that similar to my last question buy it seems like I put on the wrong side of the code. I stated int counter = 0 inside the for statement, I really have much to learn and practice. Thank you kind sir.